# disable mouseover interaction JointJS diagram

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am trying to remove the mouseover actions that happen over links and Rects.

I tried adding `interactive: false` to the `joint.dia.Paper` object - this does not help fully. I still see changes on mouse over. I want link (especially) to not respond on mouse over.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You could add an event listener to links and rects container that will handle `onmouseover` event. If an `mouseover ` event occurs on any element you don't want to, then you block it by returning `false`. I hope I get your problem correctly.

Comment: @sunpietro the jointjs documentation does not show how to add `onmouseover` listener. Could you please show an example? I am able to detect changes using `link.on('change:vertices', someChange)` (that calls the `someChange` function when the vertices have been dragged.  How can I do that for mouseover?

Comment: Isn't this just a CSS thing? Simply remove any hover CSS properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this you have to understand how the SVG markup for links is built up. The documentation explains it pretty well:

http://jointjs.com/tutorial#link-styling

If you need to check in more detail about the CSS class structure, I find it useful to use Inspect Element on your browser.

Once you understand this you will see that you can do what you are asking for using CSS. For a demo look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/azt8jpam/1/

For links you need to set `display: none` on the `connection-wrap`, `link-tools`, `marker-vertices` and `marker-arrowhead` classes.

For completeness you could also set `cursor: auto` on the shapes. For example

```
.element.basic.Rect {
    cursor: auto
}
```

Comment: fiddle not working anymore. Adding external sources will solve it. Add jquery, lodash, backbone and jointjs, and will work again